# Compability of Brew Cask VirtualBox and Parallels?

Tags: homebrew, virtualization, parallels-desktop, virtualbox, compatibility

I have a Parallels Desktop 12 for Mac installed and for a Vagrantfile I need to have virtualbox that I could install with brew such that `brew install caskroom/cask/virtualbox`.

I tested Parallels Desktop 12 and VirtualBox from Brew Cask -- and so far they have worked side-by-side fine. The VirtualBox from Brew Cask apparently installs the Oracle VirtualBox.

Anyway with the future compability issues in mind,

**What is the compability status of Parallels and Virtualbox and is it possible to have them side-by-side? Are there some potential pitfalls?**

Comment: Intriguing - I wonder if Parallels support or VBox support has recommendations for if their kernel extensions conflict with others. I'm eagerly awaiting the day when containers and VM don't need kext so we don't need to think about this. +1

Comment: I never had a problem running them side-by-side using the Oracle VBox installer though. But you may also upgrade to  **Parallels Desktop 12 for Mac Pro Edition** and use the free [vagrant-parallels](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels) provider (instead of installing VBox).

Comment: JFYI: there's also a limited and more or less experimental [vagrant provider for xhyve](https://github.com/sirn/vagrant-xhyve) > [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) > [Apple Hypervisor.framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hypervisor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the brew cask virtualbox and Parallels Desktop 12 seem to be compatible. I tested them and they are working together.**

---

Anyway if they become incompatible at some point, there are also other alternatives. As mentioned in the comments, other alternatives contain

- Parallels Desktop 12 for Mac Pro Edition where you can use the free [vagrant-parallels](https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels)
- also an experimental vagrant provider for xhyve > shave > Apple > Hypervisor.framework by this [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291124/compability-of-brew-cask-virtualbox-and-parallels#comment367551_291124)